# Deezer app FC on samsung gear s

Tags: tizen-wearable-sdk

The deezer app for tizen stops on startup.
On phone on Gear following errors occurs. 
Phone  error = remote connection lost
Gear = an error occured, connection disconnected .check gear manager setup. ?!!?!

Comment: Can you please share the log so that we can check in details of the error?

Comment: how should i log it?
this is shown @ the same time

on smartphone - deezer gear controller stopped
on gear s - no music is playing, or you havn't rights to play please check deezer app